# Android TabLayout with ViewPager performance issue when changing tab

Tags: java, android, performance, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have in my android app a login/signup view containing a TabLayout that I setup with a ViewPager. It looks like this :

[LoginFragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zopO4.png)

[SignupFragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93PDx.png)

Even if the two layouts are simple, the page changing is really slow. However, the buttons or the text fields on the fragment are smooth.

**ViewPager & TabLayout creation**

```
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.railz_auth_tab_layout);
    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.railz_auth_view_pager);

    pager.setAdapter(new RailzAuthPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));

    pager.setCurrentItem(page);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(pager);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setText("Connexion");
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setText("S'inscrire");
}
```

**ViewPagerAdapter**

```
public class RailzAuthPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

private ArrayList<Fragment> mFragments;

public RailzAuthPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);

    initPages();
}

private void initPages() {
    mFragments = new ArrayList<>();

    mFragments.add(RailzLoginFragment.newInstance());
    mFragments.add(RailzSignupFragment.newInstance());
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return mFragments.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mFragments.size();
}
```

I am just inflating the layouts in the Login and Signup fragments.

Any ideas about what could go wrong ?

Thank you,